# Parse Text with Powershell Using IndexOf

Tags: powershell, parsing, indexof

I've read all the articles that are referenced here, but I'm missing something obvious in my code.  I have the following text file:

```
d:/mev/doc1.xls
d:/mev/doc2.xls
d:/mev/doc3.xls
d:/mev/doc4.doc
d:/mev/doc5.doc
```

And I'm trying to parse out all the files that have .xls as extensions.  The parsing code appears to be working, but it's not looping through the entire file.  Here's my code:

```
$array = Get-Content "Q:\mev\pattern.txt" -raw
foreach($item in $array)
{     
    $firstref = $array.IndexOf("/mev/")
    $lastref = $array.IndexOf("xls")
    $array.Substring($firstindex+7,$lastref+2)
}
```

And here's the output:

```
PS Q:\mev> .\read3.ps1
doc1.xls
d:/m
```

What exactly am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `-Raw` switch, because you want to iterate through every line in the file. With `-Raw`, the file will be read as single multiline string instead of an array.

Also, why so difficult? If I understand correctly this will return what you seek:

```
Get-Content "Q:\mev\pattern.txt" |
Where-Object { $_ -like '*.xls' }
```

If all you need are the filenames without the path, append
`| ForEach-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_)}` to that.